Is envy towards God a sin?
After some great set backs in my life I have started worshipping Lord Krishna and Bhagavad Gita and tried to think really hard about surrender.
Recently some really painful and strange emotions have surged and taken hold of my mind. While these are clearly distorted and incoherent, one theme is common: that of envy.
I have no idea how to deal with this. I am praying real hard but that is only intensifying the feelings. I have no guru to address these issues to.
I wonder if this is just a phase or whether I am some kind of a demon inside. When the Lord is depicted as being the Supreme, having all opulences, served by all goddesses of fortune, lordship over all universes, infinite in extent, knowledge, power, beauty etc. and I am a mere insignificant, powerless, ugly jiva. To think that this is my eternal position, something that can never be changed makes feel depressed at best and envious at worst. Did God create me to just poke fun at my insignificance and get some giggles as I sail through this terrible Samasara?
Such are my thoughts. I need some help. I don't want to end up like the envious Shishupala. Please help.

Envy will only lead to further agony as one cannot try and become envious like Shishupala that Krishna Himself will come and give Moksa. According to shastras, the infinitesimal soul experiences even greater happiness than the infinte Krishna in meditation. So the soul is not 'inferior' than bhagavan. This envy you're referring to is merely agitation of the mind which will need to be fixed by regulating food, sleep, and lust.

if you cannot overcome lust, lust for God. If you cannot overcome greed, be greedy for God. If you cannot overcome hate, hate God. If you cannot overcome envy, be envious of God. Fill your thoughts of God.

first of all jiva what are its characteristics 15:7 BG mavaiamsa jiva lokha jiva bhutha. you are similar to god. i.e he is sachchidhanda roopa that is light effulegence you are like sparkle this takes away ugliness in external apperance.. every jiva is light efflugence.. Second Shishupala is composed of 2 jiva one demon and another is jaya dvarapalakha of vaikuta(lord krishnas ultimate abode) one this satvikka jiva enters vaikuta whereas shishupala demon certainly went to andhamas..

Get initiation from proper vaishnavite guru.. this will reduce negative tendencies, sriman madvacharya tells that if jiva with proper resolve can reach the adobe of sri krishna.. Second is food control, never take beef always take satvik food associate with devotees.. if possible visit ganges have bath while bath think of thiruvikrama feet from which ganes flows and unto your head absolving most sinful reaction..

There are enough land mines in hindu philosophy, those hate god reach heavenly abode. this are fallacy to make more evil minded people to fall down. Always user you intelligence think of krishna feet as all supreme, when somebody tells that you will be god or utimately jiva can be become never accept this traps, they themselves didnt understand or they are proceeding to andhamas, in their path they wanted to take more people

1. The Nature of Envy and Surrender in the Bhagavad Gita
Understanding Envy:

Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 16, Verses 4-5: "Pride, arrogance, conceit, anger, harshness, and ignorance—these qualities belong to those of demonic nature. But the qualities of the divine are fearlessness, purity of heart, steadfastness in knowledge and yoga, charity, self-control, and sacrifice."
Krishna teaches that negative emotions like envy are characteristics of those influenced by the "asuric" (demonic) nature. However, these qualities can be overcome through spiritual discipline, devotion, and cultivating divine qualities such as purity of heart and self-control.


Surrender to the Supreme:

Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 18, Verse 66: "Abandon all varieties of dharma and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear."
Krishna assures that complete surrender to Him can free us from all negative influences, including envy and despair. This surrender is not a sign of weakness but a profound act of faith and trust in the divine.

Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 9, Verse 29: "I am equally disposed to all living entities. I am neither inimical nor partial to anyone. But those who render service unto Me in devotion are in Me, and I am in them."
This verse reinforces the idea that Krishna is not indifferent or mocking. He is the well-wisher of all beings, and by sincerely offering devotion, one can establish a deep, personal connection with Him.


2. The Story of Shishupala: From Hate to Liberation
Shishupala’s story is a profound example of how deep enmity and hatred towards God can lead to ultimate liberation.
Background:
Shishupala, the king of Chedi, was born with three eyes and four arms. It was prophesied that he would be killed by the person who caused his extra limbs to disappear. When Krishna, his cousin, took Shishupala into his lap as a child, the extra limbs vanished, indicating that Krishna would be his slayer.
Despite this, Shishupala grew up with intense hatred toward Krishna. He insulted and blasphemed Krishna repeatedly, harboring deep envy and enmity. He opposed Krishna at every opportunity, particularly during the Rajasuya Yajna, where he insulted Krishna openly.
Shishupala's Death and Liberation:
According to the Mahabharata, during the Rajasuya Yajna performed by Yudhishthira, Shishupala once again insulted Krishna. Despite the numerous insults, Krishna remained patient, as He had promised Shishupala's mother that He would forgive a hundred offenses before taking action.
After Shishupala crossed the limit, Krishna used His Sudarshana Chakra to decapitate him. At that moment, something remarkable happened—Shishupala's soul merged into Krishna, attaining moksha (liberation).
Significance:
Shishupala’s story illustrates that even those who harbor intense hatred towards God can attain liberation if their minds are fully absorbed in Him, even if in a negative way. This is a profound demonstration of Krishna's grace and the transformative power of divine contact.
In some interpretations, Shishupala is considered an example of how total absorption in Krishna, even through enmity, ultimately leads to liberation. This doesn’t justify negative feelings but highlights the boundless mercy of Krishna, who can transform even the most negative emotions into a path to liberation.
3. Transformation from Hate to Devotion:
The Story of Valmiki:
Valmiki, originally known as Ratnakara, was a ruthless bandit who lived by robbing and killing travelers. His heart was filled with greed and hatred, and he showed no mercy to anyone. However, an encounter with the sage Narada transformed his life.
Narada advised Ratnakara to chant the name of Lord Rama. Though initially unable to pronounce it correctly, through sincere effort and devotion, Ratnakara's heart was purified. He later became the revered sage Valmiki, the author of the Ramayana, one of the most important texts in Hinduism.
Significance:
Valmiki’s transformation from a life of sin and hatred to becoming a saint shows that no matter how deep one’s negative emotions or sinful actions, sincere devotion and guidance from a guru or divine intervention can lead to redemption and spiritual growth.
4. Practical Steps for Overcoming Envy and Developing Devotion

Chanting and Meditation: Just as Valmiki was transformed by chanting the name of Rama, you can focus on chanting the Hare Krishna mantra or other names of the Lord to purify your mind and heart.

Selfless Service (Seva): Engage in acts of service without expectation of reward. This helps to dissolve the ego and replace envy with humility.

Study of Scriptures: Continue to study the Bhagavad Gita and other scriptures, which offer wisdom and guidance. Understanding the teachings of the Gita deeply can provide clarity and peace.

Community and Support: Even though you don’t have a personal guru, associating with a spiritual community can provide the support and guidance you need.

Practice Brahmacharya: While doing the above plz practice Brahmacharya this will help you very much


Your struggle with envy and feelings of insignificance is part of your spiritual journey, and these emotions can be overcome through sincere devotion and surrender to Krishna. Remember that Krishna's grace is infinite, and even those who struggle with negative emotions can attain His love and protection. By following the teachings of the Bhagavad Gita and drawing inspiration from stories like Shishupala's and Valmiki's, you can transform these feelings into a deeper connection with the Divine.
